# call Static block, in header section (magento2)

Tags: magento2, cms

I have created cms block with id ="headerlink"

I want to add this in header area of magento 2.

My theme, is default magento theme. I am adding following code, in module-theme\default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="headerlink">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">headerlink</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: did you flush your magento caches?

Comment: yes I have cleared them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to get your issue resolved.

```
 <referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="some_name" as="header" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="headerlink" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
```